# Can you reverse engineer animated UV's?

Tags: rendering, animation, uv, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have a scene with animated lights so that the light and shadow changes dramatically over its 900 frames.

Is there any way to kind of reverse engineer the lights and shadows in the animation so that it shows up on the UV image. Basically baking the shadows in, but animated, so instead of baking shadows onto a single UV map, it creates a 900 image sequence which could then, in turn, be mapped back onto the object as an animated UV.

And bonus points if this can be done in EEVEE. I'm much more interested in shadow placement and speed than quality/realism.

I'm not the most advanced user, so please excuse me if I'm using incorrect terminology.

Comment: Why do you want to animate in a single texture and then animate the UVs? Just baking into an image sequence and then using an image texture node in image sequence mode does the job.

Comment: @L0Lock forgive me, I don't quite follow re baking into an image sequence. Long story short, this is for a large projection mapping project. I'm animating lights/shadows inside a model of the event space, which I would (ideally) render out on individual objects/surfaces (walls, stairs, etc), take those into After Effects where I render out the flat files for the projection. What I render in Blender needs to be laid flat like a UV map. I need to render each object as though it's unfolded/unwrapped. So if the object is a cube, I need it rendered as a six-paneled cross. Does that make sense?